# creating mysql Tables automatically from excel files in folder using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Suppose this is the folder I have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQo9n.jpg)

From the above folder i should be able to all create tables in mysql like CricketWorldCup,Tennis Championships etc from  reading the excel files.So instead of having the create table tablename statement multiple times what can i do to create all the tables in mysql from the excel files in python so that just by adding a new excel file in the folder I have the table readily created in mysql.
Please help me with this question as I have been stuck on it for a long time.Please can anyone post the code for reading the excel files and automatically create the tables in mysql using python(The column names in the excel sheet and MySql should be the same)

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the into smaller problems

1. Read Excel files
2. Connect to database
3. Insert into database

And solve those using these lines of code. Reminds that you need to install the libraries first. Let's assume you use `pip`.

You might not need `pandas` or `sqlalchemy`, but using them will make this process much more easier.

`pip install pandas sqlalchemy pymysql`

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy

# connect db
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:passwd@localhost:3306/db_name')
engine.connect()

# reading and insert one file at a time
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    # only process excels files
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
    if extension == 'xlsx':
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.abspath(file))
        df.to_sql(file_basename, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: File "c:/Users/srich/Desktop/Match The Following/tester_file.py", line 16, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 350, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  Permission error by .vs.These are the errors I got

Comment: It's problem on Windows where you not provide full path. I have updated the code at `pd.read_excel(os.path.abspath(file))`

Comment: No problem. If your problem is resolved, please mark the answer as correct.